# boost::asio How to asynchronously read data from client and periodically write data if any

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm very beginner  with boost::asio, so please help me.

I need write single-threaded TCP server . Server should accept client connections and continuously read from client sockets for input data. Periodically server should send data to clients . So I have some kind of problem - all examples describe case when we always have loop

1. async_receive()
2. on_receive() -> async_write()
3. on_write() -> goto 1 :)

So my decision was to use timer for checking for data to be send to socket.

I wrote test server and have very strange behavior - it's work ok if clients connected, do something and disconnected one after another with some time delta .  But if all clients disconnected simultaneously I have
situation when timer handler try to use member classes of already DESTROYED object (locking critical section).

I can't describe why ! Please help !

[This video show how it's reproduced] (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMWkD7rqf7Y&feature=youtu.be "1080p" )

Thank you !

```
#include <boost/none.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

#include <iostream>




using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::posix_time;



class CIncommingConnection ;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<CIncommingConnection> CIncommingConnectionPtr;


struct IIncomingServer
{
    virtual  void OnData(CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn, const char *pData, size_t bytes) = 0;
    virtual  void OnConnected(CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn) = 0;
    virtual  void OnDisconnected(const boost::system::error_code& err, CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn) = 0;
};



class CAutoLock
{
public:
    CAutoLock(CRITICAL_SECTION &cs)  :
      m_cs(cs)
    {
        ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }

   ~CAutoLock()
   {
       ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
   }

private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION &m_cs;
};

class CIncommingConnection :  public boost::enable_shared_from_this<CIncommingConnection>                      
                             ,boost::noncopyable 
{
public:

    CIncommingConnection(const std::string sPeerName, boost::asio::io_service  &service, IIncomingServer *pServer) :
     m_service(service)
    ,sock_(service)
    ,m_sPeerName(sPeerName) 
    ,m_pServer(pServer)
    ,m_timer(service)
    {
        ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);

        std::cout << "CIncommingConnection()"  << std::endl ;
    }


    ~CIncommingConnection()
    {
        std::cout << "CIncommingConnection()~"  << std::endl ;
        ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }


    ip::tcp::socket & sock()
    {
        return sock_;
    }



    void start()
    {
        m_pServer->OnConnected(shared_from_this());
        do_read();
        wait_for_outgoingdata();
    }


private:

    void stop()
    {      
        sock_.close();
        m_timer.cancel();
    }



    void do_read()
    {
        sock_.async_receive(buffer(read_buffer_), boost::bind(&CIncommingConnection::handler_read, this, _1, _2) );
    }



    void do_error(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn = shared_from_this();

        stop() ;

        m_pServer->OnDisconnected(error, pConn);
    }



    void handler_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            do_error(error);
            return ;
        }

        CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn = shared_from_this() ;

        m_pServer->OnData(pConn, read_buffer_, bytes);

        do_read();
    }



    void wait_for_outgoingdata()
    {
        m_timer.expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::millisec( 100 ) );
        m_timer.async_wait( boost::bind( &CIncommingConnection::on_output_queue_timer, this, _1 ) );
    }



    void on_output_queue_timer(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
        {
            return ;
        }

        CAutoLock oLock(m_cs);

        if (!m_sOutBuf.empty())
            sock_.async_send(buffer(m_sOutBuf), boost::bind(&CIncommingConnection::handler_write, this, _1, _2) );
        else
            wait_for_outgoingdata();
    }


    void handler_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes)
    {    
        if (error)
            return ;


        if (bytes)
        {
            m_sOutBuf = m_sOutBuf.substr(bytes, m_sOutBuf.length()-bytes);
        }

        wait_for_outgoingdata();
    }



private:
    ip::tcp::socket sock_;

    enum { max_msg = 1024 };
    char read_buffer_[max_msg];
    char write_buffer_[max_msg];


    boost::asio::io_service        &m_service ;   
    std::string                     m_sPeerName ;
    std::string                     m_sOutBuf;
    CRITICAL_SECTION                m_cs ;
    IIncomingServer                *m_pServer;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer     m_timer;
};






class CIncomingServer :   public boost::enable_shared_from_this<CIncomingServer>                      
                         , public IIncomingServer
                         , boost::noncopyable 
{

public:

    CIncomingServer(boost::asio::io_service  &service,
        unsigned int port,
        bool bAllowManyConnections,
        const std::string sPeerName) :

      m_acceptor (service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), port), false)
     ,m_sPeerName(sPeerName)
     ,m_port(port) 
     ,m_service(service)
     ,m_timer(service)
     ,m_bAllowManyConnections(bAllowManyConnections)
    {
    }



    ~CIncomingServer()
    {
    }



    void run()
    {
        CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn (new CIncommingConnection(m_sPeerName, m_service, this));
        m_clients.push_back( pConn );


        m_acceptor.async_accept(pConn->sock(), boost::bind(&CIncomingServer::handle_accept, this, _1));

        m_timer.expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::millisec( 500 ) );
        m_timer.async_wait( boost::bind( &CIncomingServer::on_timer, this ) );
    }




private:

    void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code & err)
    {
        m_clients.back()->start();

        CIncommingConnectionPtr pConnNew (new CIncommingConnection(m_sPeerName, m_service, this));
        m_clients.push_back( pConnNew );

        m_acceptor.async_accept(pConnNew->sock(), boost::bind(&CIncomingServer::handle_accept, this,  _1));
    }


    //IIncomingServer
    virtual  void OnData(CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn, const char *pData, size_t bytes)
    {
        std::cout << "Data received" << std::endl ;
    }


    virtual  void OnConnected(CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn)
    {
        std::cout << "Client connected" << std::endl ;
    }


    virtual  void OnDisconnected(const boost::system::error_code& err, CIncommingConnectionPtr pConn)
    {
        std::cout << "Client disconnected" << std::endl ;

        auto it = std::find(m_clients.begin(), m_clients.end(), pConn) ;
        if (it != m_clients.end())
        {
            m_clients.erase(it);
        }

    }



    void on_timer()
    {
        //if (NeedTerminate())
        //{
        //    m_service.stop();
        //    return ;
        //}

        m_timer.expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::millisec( 500 ) );
        m_timer.async_wait( boost::bind( &CIncomingServer::on_timer, this ) );
    }



private:
    ip::tcp::acceptor  m_acceptor ;

    std::vector<CIncommingConnectionPtr> m_clients;
    std::string m_sPeerName ;
    unsigned int m_port ;
    boost::asio::io_service       &m_service ;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer    m_timer;
    bool                           m_bAllowManyConnections; 
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    boost::asio::io_service  service ;


    boost::shared_ptr<CIncomingServer> pServer;

    try
    {
        pServer.reset( new CIncomingServer(service, 8000,  false, "BS Server"));        
        pServer->run();
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error &err)
    {
        std::cout << "Error : " << err.what() << std::endl ;
        return 0 ;
    }

    service.run();

    return 0 ;


}
```

Comment: -1. Is this a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? I doubt it.

Comment: Sorry, Abyx - but I don't agree with your doubts. For example  what kind of details are not  importan  , you think,  in  this sample ? But thank you for criticism !

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: you should bind the completion handlers to a shared_ptr returned from `shared_from_this()`, not to plain `this` (so called `shared_from_this` idiom). This way you ensure the correct automatic management of your connection objects lifespan.

Technically, the following happens now: `do_error` causes 2 actions to take place:

1. timer cancellation (which is asynchronous operation) removal of
2. `CIncommingConnectionPtr` from a container (which is synchronous
   operation).

At the point (2) the connection gets destroyed, as there are no other `shared_ptr`s holding it. Now the [timer completion handler comes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html)... Crash!

Comment: Thank you for answer!

It's look like it's correct , but I can't make proper conclusion from it :-(

After passing shared_from_this() instead this to async handlers my program don't crashed any more, but not all instances of CIncommingConnection is destroyed.
It's look like I miss about some referencing , and object still alive.

I will try to investigate this situation today ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @user1503944 well, at a glance, I don't see any "eternal" `shared_ptr`s in the above code (even after binding to `shared_from_this`). Perhaps, your real code differs from the one you posted. (BTW, I'd recommend you to avoid explicit locks on the buffer - instead, you could just `post()` any buffer-related code to the `io_service`.)

Comment: @user1503944: A brief look at the code suggest that the `CIncommingConnection::on_output_queue_timer()` call chain may be maintaining the reference.  It is possible that the call chain continues even though `timer.cancel()` is invoked.  For details on this behavior, see the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_deadline_timer.cancel.overload1.remarks) remarks.  To resolve it, consider returning in `on_output_queue_timer()` on error or if `sock_.is_open()` is false.

Comment: @Tanner Sansbury but along with timer cancellation he calls `sock_.close()`, so any subsequent i/o on `sock_` will fail anyway (and break the chain).

Comment: @IgorR. The `wait_for_outgoingdata()` chain only attempts I/O on `sock_` if `m_sOutBuf` is not empty; however, `m_sOutBuf` appears to remain empty in the posted code.  Breaking the chain when `sock_.is_open()` is false seems like a reasonable predicate to guarantee the chain breaks after `stop()` has been invoked.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now all work as expected . Your Solution absolutely right

1. Pass shared_from_this() as "this" via bind for handlers
2. on_error we need just close socket
3. on timer handler we check socket, if it closed we just don't proceed with timer loop, and last reference to object is removed , and it's disposed correctly !

Brilliant - Thank you !